# how to recursively iterate over XML tags in Python using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to iterate over all nodes in a tree using ElementTree.

I do something like:

```py
tree = ET.parse("/tmp/test.xml")

root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    ### do something with child
```

The problem is that child is an Element object and not `ElementTree` object, so I can't further look into it and recurse to iterate over its elements. Is there a way to iterate differently over "root" so that it iterates over the top-level nodes in the tree (immediate children) and returns the same class as the root itself?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To iterate over all nodes, use the [`iter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.iter) method on the [`ElementTree`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-objects), not the root Element.

The root is an Element, just like the other elements in the tree and only really has context of its own attributes and children. The `ElementTree` has the context for all Elements.

For example, given this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

You can do the following

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
>>> for elem in tree.iter():
...     print elem
... 
<Element 'data' at 0x10b2d7b50>
<Element 'country' at 0x10b2d7b90>
<Element 'rank' at 0x10b2d7bd0>
<Element 'year' at 0x10b2d7c50>
<Element 'gdppc' at 0x10b2d7d10>
<Element 'neighbor' at 0x10b2d7e90>
<Element 'neighbor' at 0x10b2d7ed0>
<Element 'country' at 0x10b2d7f10>
<Element 'rank' at 0x10b2d7f50>
<Element 'year' at 0x10b2d7f90>
<Element 'gdppc' at 0x10b2d7fd0>
<Element 'neighbor' at 0x10b2db050>
<Element 'country' at 0x10b2db090>
<Element 'rank' at 0x10b2db0d0>
<Element 'year' at 0x10b2db110>
<Element 'gdppc' at 0x10b2db150>
<Element 'neighbor' at 0x10b2db190>
<Element 'neighbor' at 0x10b2db1d0>
```

Comment: How do you print the values as well?

Comment: Is it possible to do this with `fromstring()` instead of  `parse()`? The former directly gives you the root Element

Comment: Any idea how to modify this to display if its a subelemnt or attribute etc?

Comment: is it possible to access the exact location of the element in the hierarchy?

Comment: To access values, `elem.attrib` will give you a dict of the attribues and their values in the element.

Comment: I get `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Response` and want to parse the response of a `requests.post(location, data=xml, headers={'soapaction...}`

Comment: tried to edit it, it should be: print(elem)

Answer (score 22):

Adding to Robert Christie's answer it is possible to iterate over all nodes using `fromstring()` by converting the Element to an ElementTree:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

e = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml_string))
for elt in e.iter():
    print "%s: '%s'" % (elt.tag, elt.text)
```

Answer (score 15):

In addition to Robert Christie's accepted answer, printing the values and tags separately is very easy:

```
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
for elem in tree.iter():
    print(elem.tag, elem.text)
```

Answer (score 13):

you can also access specific elements like this:

```
country= tree.findall('.//country')
```

then loop over `range(len(country))`
and access

Comment: This works perfectly.  Is it a new feature?  I wonder why no one else mentions it.  How does it work? (Having trouble searching for `.//`)

Comment: `.//` is part of Xpath. Try Googling that.

Answer (score 2):

While `iter()` is all very good, I needed a way to walk an xml hierarchy while tracking the nesting level, and `iter()` doesn't help at all with that. I wanted something like `iterparse()` which emits start and end events at each level of the hierarchy, but I already have the ElementTree so didn't want the unnecessary step/overhead of convert to string and re-parsing that using `iterparse()` would require.

Surprised I couldn't find this, I had to write it myself:

```
def iterwalk(root, events=None, tags=None):
    """Incrementally walks XML structure (like iterparse but for an existing ElementTree structure)
    Returns an iterator providing (event, elem) pairs.
    Events are start and end
    events is a list of events to emit - defaults to ["start","end"]
    tags is a single tag or a list of tags to emit events for - if empty/None events are generated for all tags
    """
    # each stack entry consists of a list of the xml element and a second entry initially None
    # if the second entry is None a start is emitted and all children of current element are put into the second entry
    # if the second entry is a non-empty list the first item in it is popped and then a new stack entry is created
    # once the second entry is an empty list, and end is generated and then stack is popped
    stack = [[root,None]]
    tags = [] if tags is None else tags if type(tags) == list else [tags]
    events = events or ["start","end"]
    def iterator():
        while stack:
            elnow,children = stack[-1]
            if children is None:
                # this is the start of elnow so emit a start and put its children into the stack entry
                if ( not tags or elnow.tag in tags ) and "start" in events:
                    yield ("start",elnow)
                # put the children into the top stack entry
                stack[-1][1] = list(elnow)
            elif len(children)>0:
                # do a child and remove it
                thischild = children.pop(0)
                # and now create a new stack entry for this child
                stack.append([thischild,None])                
            else:
                # finished these children - emit the end
                if ( not tags or elnow.tag in tags ) and "end" in events:
                    yield ("end",elnow)
                stack.pop()
    return iterator

# myxml is my parsed XML which has nested Binding tags, I want to count the depth of nesting

# Now explore the structure
it = iterwalk( myxml, tags='Binding'))
level = 0
for event,el in it():
    if event == "start":
        level += 1
        
    print( f"{level} {el.tag=}" )
    
    if event == "end":
        level -= 1
```

The stack is used so that you can emit the start events as you go down the hierarchy and then correctly backtrack. The last entry in the stack is initially [el, None] so the start event for el is emitted and the second entry is update to [el,children] with each child being removed from the children as it is entered, until after last child has been done the entry is [el,[]] at which point the end event for el is emitted and the top entry removed from the stack.

I did it this way with the stack because I'm not fond of debugging recursive code and anyway I'm not sure how to write a recursive iterator function.

Here's a recursive version which is easier to understand but would be difficult to debug if it weren't so simple and something went wrong - and I learned about `yield from` :-)

```
def iterwalk1(root, events=None, tags=None):
    """Recuirsive version - Incrementally walks XML structure (like iterparse but for an existing ElementTree structure)
    Returns an iterator providing (event, elem) pairs.
    Events are start and end
    events is a list of events to emit - defaults to ["start","end"]
    tags is a single tag or a list of tags to emit events for - if None or empty list then events are generated for all tags
    """
    tags = [] if tags is None else tags if type(tags) == list else [tags]
    events = events or ["start","end"]
    
    def recursiveiterator(el,suppressyield=False):
        if not suppressyield and ( not tags or el.tag in tags ) and "start" in events:
            yield ("start",el)
        for child in list(el):
            yield from recursiveiterator(child)
        if not suppressyield and  ( not tags or el.tag in tags ) and "end" in events:
            yield ("end",el)
            
    def iterator():
        yield from recursiveiterator( root, suppressyield=True )
        
    return iterator
```

Comment: Please add example input and output

Answer (score 0):

excellent solution for xml to dict :
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68082847/3505444

```
def etree_to_dict(t):
    if type(t) is ET.ElementTree: return etree_to_dict(t.getroot())
    return {
        **t.attrib,
        'text': t.text,
        **{e.tag: etree_to_dict(e) for e in t}
    }
```

and :

```
def nested_dict_pairs_iterator(dict_obj):
    ''' This function accepts a nested dictionary as argument
        and iterate over all values of nested dictionaries
    '''
    # Iterate over all key-value pairs of dict argument
    for key, value in dict_obj.items():
        # Check if value is of dict type
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # If value is dict then iterate over all its values
            for pair in  nested_dict_pairs_iterator(value):
                yield (key, *pair)
        else:
            # If value is not dict type then yield the value
            yield (key, value)
```

finally :

```
root_dict = etree_to_dict(myet.root)
for pair in nested_dict_pairs_iterator(root_dict):
    print(pair)
```