# python prints document{} when try to iterate over xml and print tags and attributes

Tags: python, xml, file

I have an xml document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<root>
  <document>
    <docId>CVE-2002-2131.txt</docId>
    <sentences>
      <sentence id="1">
        <tokens>
          <token id="1">
            <word>Directory</word>
            <lemma>Directory</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>0</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>9</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>NNP</POS>
          </token>
          <token id="2">
            <word>traversal</word>
            <lemma>traversal</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>10</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>19</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>NN</POS>
          </token>
          <token id="3">
            <word>vulnerability</word>
            <lemma>vulnerability</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>20</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>33</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>NN</POS>
          </token>
          <token id="4">
            <word>in</word>
            <lemma>in</lemma>
            <CharacterOffsetBegin>34</CharacterOffsetBegin>
            <CharacterOffsetEnd>36</CharacterOffsetEnd>
            <POS>IN</POS>
          </token>
           ...
```

For some reason when I try to iterate over the xml and print the child tag and attribute, it's printing document {}.

This is my code:

```
print("-------")
#extract from xml file and get fields ready for csv for this document
newFilePathOneXml=os.path.join("ners",filenameWithoutExtension,'CVE-2002-2131.txt.xml')
print(newFilePathOneXml)
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
tree = et.parse(newFilePathOneXml)
print("here2")
root = tree.getroot()
print("here3")
for child in root:
    print("here4")
    print (child.tag, child.attrib)
    print("here5")
#f = open(newFilePathOneXml,"r")
#print(f.read())
et.dump(myRoot)
```

This is what gets printed:

```
---
ners\nvdcve-1.1-2002\CVE-2002-2131.txt.xml
here2
here3
here4
document {}
here5
...........prints xml document here................
```

I'm trying to follow instructions at this link to [get the xml out and access with child tags](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).  All I really need are the tags called word in each token element.  I'm going to get the word values and write to string.

Any idea why it's not working?  The filename is cve-2002-2131.txt.xml.

Update: I added file read and printed file contents, and then tried et.dump(myRoot) and it does print the entire xml that way, like it did to read the file and print(f.read()).

Update2: 
I got this to work but I'm not sure what the best way to get the token element values is.

```
for elem in tree.iter():
    print (elem)
```

prints:

```
here3
<Element 'root' at 0x000002588AF2A5E8>
here4
here5
<Element 'document' at 0x000002588AF2A548>
here4
here5
<Element 'docId' at 0x000002588AF2AB88>
here4
here5
<Element 'sentences' at 0x000002588AF89638>
here4
here5
<Element 'sentence' at 0x000002588AF89688>
here4
here5
<Element 'tokens' at 0x000002588AF89CC8>
here4
here5
<Element 'token' at 0x0000025884CFAC28>
...
```

I'm looking at [iterate over tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074361/how-to-recursively-iterate-over-xml-tags-in-python-using-elementtree), and there's an answer about tree.findall, but it's doing weird things.

```
tokens=tree.findall('.//tokens')
print(tokens)
#for token in range(len(tokens))  #this gives error
#    print(token)
```

prints:

```
[<Element 'tokens' at 0x00000222B2059CC8>, <Element 'tokens' at 0x00000222ABDF7958>, <Element 'tokens' at 0x00000222ABDFE318>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this:

```
print("here3")
tokens=tree.findall('.//tokens')
#print(tokens)
for tokensItem in tokens: #range(len(tokens))
    for token in tokensItem:
        print(token.find('word').text)
```

There may be a more efficient way though, so feel free to share.