# Preparing xml data for deserialization in Django

Tags: python, django, deserialization

I have model with several fields that look like this:

```
class XMLData(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   description = models.CharField()
   price = models.CharField()
```

and xml data that wrapped in string, xml data look like this:

```
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Product>
         <Name>name1</Name>
         <Description>description1</Description>
         <Price>1</Price>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>name2</Name>
         <Description>description2</Description>
         <Price>2</Price>
      </Product>
   </Main>
</Root>
```

My question is: should i replace children nodes `Product` to the parent node and should i rename tags `Name`, `Description`, `Price` to `name`, `description`, `price`?

I tried to deserialize using this code:

```
for product in serializers.deserialize("xml", xmldata):
   savedata = XMLData(product)
   savedata.save()
```

so I hoped that will rise some errors and i would understand what to do next, but there was no errors and xml data didn't save to database.

Hope you understand my problem and thank you for your answer.

Comment: There is no magic here. Django can't deserialize whatever XML you want. It is able to deserialize only format described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/#xml). And your XML doesn't fit expected format. You have to look into generic XML parsing tools (like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)) and manually create you models from parsed data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please set your comment to answer. To close this question

Comment: There is a better answer by @abu-ashraf-masnun. Feel free to accept it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are only interested in storing the product information. In that case `Product` would be a better model name than `XMLData`.

Django serializers won't help since your data is not in the correct format. However you can deserialize with lxml. Code taken from: [Converting xml to dictionary using ElementTree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684333/converting-xml-to-dictionary-using-elementtree)

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

def etree_to_dict(t):
    d = {t.tag: {} if t.attrib else None}
    children = list(t)
    if children:
        dd = defaultdict(list)
        for dc in map(etree_to_dict, children):
            for k, v in dc.iteritems():
                dd[k].append(v)
        d = {t.tag: {k:v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in dd.iteritems()}}
    if t.attrib:
        d[t.tag].update(('@' + k, v) for k, v in t.attrib.iteritems())
    if t.text:
        text = t.text.strip()
        if children or t.attrib:
            if text:
              d[t.tag]['#text'] = text
        else:
            d[t.tag] = text
    return d

e = ET.XML('''
<Root>
   <Header>
      <information>info</information>
   </Header>
   <Main>
      <Product>
         <Name>name1</Name>
         <Description>description1</Description>
         <Price>1</Price>
      </Product>
      <Product>
         <Name>name2</Name>
         <Description>description2</Description>
         <Price>2</Price>
      </Product>
   </Main>
</Root>
''')

from pprint import pprint

d = etree_to_dict(e)

pprint(d)
```

Now, instead of pretty printing, we can directly store the products:

```
d = etree_to_dict(e)

products = d['Root']['Main']['Product']

for p in products:
    product = Product()
    p.name = p['Name']
    p.description = p['Description']
    p.price = p['Price']

    p.save()
```

That should store the products to the database.