# Converting xml to dictionary with values on tags

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, elementtree

I have a XML that has attributes for each tag as the following on:

```xml
<?xml version= "1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<month xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="my.xsd">
    <day Day="2016-1-01">
        <hour Hour="00:00">
            <Variables>
                <a>211.3</a>
                <b>78.94</b>
                <c>0.6</c>
            </Variables>
        </hour>
        <hour Hour="12:00">
            <Variables>
                <a>155.5</a>
                <b>85.5</b>
                <c>0.42</c>
            </Variables>
        </hour>
    </day>
</month>
```

I am looking to parse the XML and convert to dictionary but not with the tags, with the attribute values.

I mean, how to be able to make something similar to:

```
>>> print d['2016-1-01']['12:00']['b']
>>> 85.5
```

The real XML has many more days and also hours. Is this possible?

The only way to parse it that I have been able to make is this one, but difficult if you want to look for several different variables on different times:

```
# Day
for child_day in root:
    print child_day.tag, child_day.attrib

    # Hour
    for child_hour in child_day:
        print '\t', child_hour.tag, child_hour.attrib

        # Variables
        for child_Variables in child_hour:
            print '\t\t', child_Variables.find('b').text
```

Is there any function similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684333/converting-xml-to-dictionary-using-elementtree) that makes the same for attribute case as this one instead of tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you linked is using what's called what's called [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/). It's a pretty simple and elegant solution because it will do the same thing at each level of the `ElementTree` to generate that level of the `dict`, so that function can just call itself recursively.

But if I understand you correctly, you'll be grabbing different attributes of each tag depending on what level you're at in the structure of the `ElementTree` to use as the `dict` keys, and then you'll be switching it up at the bottom level to use the tag names as keys, and the text as the values. So I couldn't come up with a solution quite as elegant as the one in the answer you linked.

We can make use of dict comprehension too, but we're going to have to use it a few times (at least for the solution that I came up with).

It sounds like you're hoping to get a `dict` that looks like this (given your sample XML):

```json
{
    "2016-1-01": {
        "12:00": {
            "a": "155.5",
            "b": "85.5",
            "c": "0.42",
        },
        "00:00": {
            "a": "211.3",
            "b": "78.94",
            "c": "0.6",
        },
    },
}
```

To do this, you'll need 3 functions; 1 to handle the creation of each level of the `dict` (days, hours, and variables). Here's what they look like:

```py
def month_etree_to_dict(month):
    d_list = month.getchildren()
    d_dict = {d.attrib["Day"]: day_etree_to_dict(d) for d in d_list}
    return d_dict

def day_etree_to_dict(day):
    h_list = day.getchildren()
    h_dict = {h.attrib["Hour"]: hour_etree_to_dict(h) for h in h_list}
    return h_dict

def hour_etree_to_dict(hour):
    v_list = hour.getchildren()[0].getchildren()
    v_dict = {v.tag: v.text for v in v_list}
    return v_dict
```

The function `month_etree_to_dict` generates a `dict` where the keys are the dates for each day. The values are dictionaries that are generated using the `day_etree_to_dict` function. The `day_etree_to_dict` function does the same thing for each hour by calling the `hour_etree_to_dict` function. The `hour_etree_to_dict` function works a little differently by jumping an extra level down in the `ElementTree` so it can iterate through the `<Variables>` `Element`'s children (`<a>`, `<b>`, and `<c>`) using their tag names as the keys for the `dict` and their text for the values.

I hope this makes sense and is useful for you.

Comment: Simply perfect! I really understand much better dictionaries with your explanation. Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

I often use recursive `defaultdict` when converting XML to dict, like so:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict


def Tree():
    return defaultdict(Tree)

tree = ET.parse('x.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
d = Tree()
for day in root.findall('day'):
    for hour in day.findall('hour'):
        for v in hour.findall('./Variables/*'):
            d[day.attrib['Day']][hour.attrib['Hour']][v.tag] = v.text

print d['2016-1-01']['12:00']['b']
```

Reference:

- https://gist.github.com/hrldcpr/2012250
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#finding-interesting-elements