# Extract data XML --> DICT in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I have this xml file which contains  and  inside. Though I am getting only the first one, I cannot loop through them. Here is the xml structure and code:

```
from lxml import objectify as xml_objectify
contents = open('/home/conacons/Documents/order.xml').read()
def xml_to_dict(xml_str):
""" Convert xml to dict, using lxml v3.4.2 xml processing library """
    def xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_object):
        dict_object = xml_object.__dict__
        if not dict_object:
            return xml_object
        for key, value in dict_object.items():
            dict_object[key] = xml_to_dict_recursion(value)
        return dict_object
    return xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_objectify.fromstring(xml_str))
xml_dict = xml_to_dict(contents)
#print xml_dict
for item,v in xml_dict['item']['items'].items():
    print item,v
<Order>
<item>
<customer></customer>
<status>no</status>
<amount_untaxed>7315.0</amount_untaxed>
<name>Test/001</name>
<confirmation_date>False</confirmation_date>
<order_id>8</order_id>
<items>
<item><list_price>16.5</list_price><description>False</description><weight>0.0</weight><default_code/><id>18</id><uom>Unit(s)</uom> <name>iPod</name></item><item><list_price>12.5</list_price><description>False</description><weight>0.0</weight><default_code>M-Wir</default_code><id>19</id><uom>Unit(s)</uom><name>Mouse, Wireless</name>     </item>
```

Whrn i run this code I am getting only one of the ITEMS. How can I make the loop to get all items in items? THanks
(output):
item {'list_price': 16.5, 'description': 'False', 'weight': 0.0, 'default_code': u'', 'id': 18, 'uom': 'Unit(s)', 'name': 'iPod'}

Comment: Can you post a valid xml document? This one has some errors. For example there are no closing tags for Order, first "item" tag, etc.

Comment: Here is the full order.xml doc
https://pastebin.com/sUsbRqAz

Comment: You can either use xml and process it via xml libraries or use json and convert it into dict for processing. Converting xml into dict for processing is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Isn't this a copy of [https://stackoverflow.com/q/7684333/3147247](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7684333/3147247)?

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem in your approach. XML object is not converted to `dict` because `dict` object can't have duplicate keys. For example, in your case when you call `xml_object.__dict__` for `xml_object` with several `item` children tags it returns a `dict` with only one `item` key. So you should use `getchildren` method instead of `__init__`. But there is another problem. For `xml_object` corresponding to `items` tag from your example the next code also won't work correctly:

```
for child in xml_object.getchildren():
    dict_object[child.tag] = xml_to_dict_recursion(child)
```

The reason as you understand is that in all loop iterations `child.tag` has the same value.

One possible way to resolve these problems is using `collections.defaultdict`. The code might be look like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from lxml import objectify


def xml_to_dict(xml_str):
    def xml_to_dict_recursion(xml_object):
        dict_object = defaultdict(list)
        if not xml_object.__dict__:
            return xml_object
        for child in xml_object.getchildren():
            dict_object[child.tag].append(xml_to_dict_recursion(child))
        return dict_object
    return xml_to_dict_recursion(objectify.fromstring(xml_str))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    contents = open('input.xml').read()
    xml_dict = xml_to_dict(contents)
    for value in xml_dict['item'][0]['items'][0]['item']:
        print(dict(value))
```

In this case the output is:

```
{'uom': ['Unit(s)'], 'default_code': [''], 'description': ['False'], 'name': ['iPod'], 'weight': [0.0], 'list_price': [16.5], 'id': [18]}
{'uom': ['Unit(s)'], 'default_code': ['M-Wir'], 'description': ['False'], 'name': ['Mouse, Wireless'], 'weight': [0.0], 'list_price': [12.5], 'id': [19]}
```

But in my opinion this approach is not so convinient and more comfortable way is just parsing xml document itself with `lxml.objectify` (see the [docs](http://lxml.de/objectify.html)). For example:

```
tree = objectify.parse('input.xml')
order = tree.getroot()
order_items = order.getchildren()
for order_item in order_items:
    print(order_item['amount_untaxed'])
    customer = order_item['customer']
    print(customer['item']['city'])
    for item in order_item['items'].getchildren():
        print(item['list_price'])
```

Comment: Cool thanks dude this works. Now because this will be a multiple order import system, i will have more than 1 item in <Order><item></item> and here another <item></item>. I can access them with `    for value in xml_dict['item'][0]['items'][0]['item']:
        #print value['list_price']
        print(dict(value))
    for value in xml_dict['item'][1]['items'][0]['item']:
        #print value['list_price']
        print(dict(value))`
But to loop through all of them withou manually writing the  xml_dict['item'][1][ or  xml_dict['item'][2][ or  xml_dict['item'][3][ ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you really need in converting xml object to dictionary? In my opinion working with `lxml` methods is more convenient.

Comment: okay so in short, how would I access all orders and items in orders without converting the xml to dict? thanks a lot

Comment: I've updated my comment with example of parsing your xml file.